# Putting ElasticSearch behind a Proxy on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

This article here (and books and other information sources on ES as well) argues for putting ES behind a proxy service:

https://dzone.com/articles/securing-your-elasticsearch-cluster-properly

> A very common mistake I see is people saying "Hey, Elasticsearch is REST over HTTP, let's just access it directly from our smart HTML clients". Well, you really don't want to do that.
>
> Have a Single Page Application that needs to query Elastic and get
>   JSONs for display? Pass it through a software façade that can do
>   request filtering, audit-logging, and most importantly -
>   password-protect your data.
>
> Without that, (a) you are for sure binding to a public IP and you
>   shouldn't, (b) you are risking unwanted changes to your data, (c) and
>   the worst — you can't control who accesses what and all your data is
>   visible for all to see. Just what's happening now with those
>   Elasticsearch clusters.
>
> Additionally, don't expose your document and index structure, or
>   couple your thin client with the data-store system serving it data.
>   Your client-side javascript really shouldn't speak Elastic DSL.
>
> Your clients should communicate with your server-side software, that
>   will in turn transform all client-side requests to Elasticsearch DSL,
>   execute the query, and then selectively transform the response from
>   Elasticsearch back to something your clients expect. And obviously
>   your server-side application can then validate the user login when
>   necessary to both authenticate and authorize his actions against the
>   data, way before any access to Elasticsearch is made. Doing it in any
>   other way just exposes you to unnecessary risk, and your data to
>   greedy hackers.

I totally agree with all the things said here when running my own ES in a private cloud. But what do you usually do when running it on AWS? I am totally new to the whole serverless world and recently I came across Google Firebase Tutorial videos where people argued to make queries from the client directly to the DB. Is this common in AWS too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having worked with AWS for a bit now, my I have to clear a misunderstanding. AWS is not equal to serverless. They offer many cloud solutions and FAAS/function-as-a-service (AWS Lambda) is only one of them.

And regardless whether you work with FAAS, IAAS or PAAS, you might always have the use case where you want to expose only a fragment of Elasticsearch's interface to the outside world. If you get Software-As-A-Service, eg ElasticCloud (hosted by Elastic the company on AWS) or deploy your own Elastic Cluster with an X-PACK license, then you can consider using XPACK security/index-limitations features. However, this takes only care of security, not simplicity. The people working on the front-end would need to know the index internals/mappings and how to make (efficient) queries in ES.

I am not even sure if X-PACK can prevent heavy to compute queries (like script queries, aggregations and deep pagination), so if you expose the API to the whole Internet, this might not be enough security.

Now what the guys in the firebase videos do (forming queries client-side) is nice and keeps the application flexible, but it might now be suitable for every use case. For example if you want to expose a public API for customers with an own client.